# Arranging 3 div - div 2 to the left - div 1 and three to the right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've got three div's - that I'd like to arrange like this

+++++++++++
+ div2 + div1 +
+ div2++++++
+____+ div3 +
+++++++++++

But when the height of div2 is less than div1 then div 3 floats left like this even if I float div 1 and div3 to the right in css.

+++++++++++
+ div2 + div1 +
++++++   div1     +
+ div3 + ___ +
+++++++++++

When resizing I get this - what is what I want when resizing.

++++++
+ div1 +
++++++
+ div2 +
++++++
+ div3 +
++++++

this is the html

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="row-item col-1_2 div1">
                <?php print render($content['field_1']) ?>
            </div>

            <div class="row-item col-1_2 div2">
                <?php print render($content['body']); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="row-item col-1_2 div3">
                <?php print render($content['field_2']); ?>
            </div>
```

So - what should my css / html be if at all possible to do?

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage floating divs and spaces you can use the *clear* css attribute as follow:

```
<style>
    #div1, #div3{
        float: right;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    #div2, #div2-1{
        float: left;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    #div2-1{
        clear: right;
    }

    #div3{
        clear: left;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div id="div1">DIV1</div>

    <div id="div2">DIV2</div>

    <div id="div2-1">DIV2-1</div>

    <div id="div3">DIV3</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the div2s height is less than in div1.